# WordPress: wp_login_form how to add class name or placeholder text

Tags: wordpress

How can I add placeholder or CSS classes to login fields using wp_login_form?

The function `wp_login_form` in `wp-includes/general-template.php` renders the login form from an array of arguments:

```
$default = array(
  'echo' => true,
  ...
  ...
);
```

and then creates the `<form>...</form>`. There is no way I can add a class name to input fields or the submit button. I want to use bootstrap classes for this purpose. Currently I have to override default classes rendered by WordPress.

I don't want to do that. For example if I want to make `username` box to look like an input with class `form-control`, I have to either write additional classes in my CSS for default WP classes or take help of jQuery to remove default classes and add mine.

What is the best way to do it? `wp_login_form` does not have attributes set for `placeholder`.

In brief I need to pass the following:
1. Pass class name from outside via an array $args,
2. Pass placeholder text for input fields

Answer (score 5):

This might be a solution, eventhough it isn't perfect.

Wordpress' functon `wp_login_form()` does not support changing the css class. And I would recommend not to use Javascript for changing the DOM when you do not absolutely have to.

My solution to modify the CSS class was to set the `echo` property to `false` so the function returns the result as a string. Then, use `str_replace()` to find the classes we want to replace and replace it with the class names we want to use.

```
$args = array(
    'echo' => false,
    // etc...
```

And now replacing the class names...

```
$output = wp_login_form( $args );
$output = str_replace( 'class="input"', 'class="df-input"', $output );
echo $output;
```

You could also convert `$output` into a `DOMDocument()` so you can replace the class names in an more elegant manner.

Answer (score 0):

According to its documentation, [`wp_login_form()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) does not receive an argument to set a class name for itself of input elements. Presumably because you wouldn't have more than one login form on the page.

It is possible to add an id to the inputs of the forms like so:

```
$args = array(
    'form_id'        => 'loginform',
    'id_username'    => 'user_login',
    'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
);
```

However, seems that in order to set other attributes such as `class` and `placeholders` you would have to use Javascript. This can be done without [JQuery](https://jquery.com/). This would look like something along the lines of `document.querySelector('#username').setAttribute("class", "username");`

[See the querySelector documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Yes, that function does not have an option to overwrite the css class. Im my opinion, this is kinda disappointing by Wordpress. Setting it with Javascript is surely not the way to go. Using sass or less code it is possible to extend the default input class with a class of your own styling, I think that would be the best option. Otherwise duplicating the wp_login_form and making it custom would be an option, but not ideal obviously.

Comment: Agreed, not ideal but I was unsure if the OP is using a pre processor to handle CSS but the JavaScript API is always there at least. Overriding `wp_login_form` is an options but in my view could lead to more maintenance because WordPress updates could break it. Hope either of the answers help.